# Using same hidden name attribute in Form

Tags: php, html

I am developing a eCommerce application, where I am displaying all the products. I am passing the price as a input hidden attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="retail_price_cost"  value="10"/>
<input type="hidden" name="wholesale_price_cost"  value="0.30"/>
<input type="submit" class="button subbutton" name="add_to_cart"  value="ADD TO CART" />
```

However, it is taking the last value from the listed products. I tried converting into an array, by using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="retail_price_cost[]"  value="10"/>
<input type="hidden" name="wholesale_price_cost[]"  value="0.30"/>
<input type="submit" class="button subbutton" name="add_to_cart[]"  value="ADD TO CART"/>
```

However, when I click on Add to cart, it is displaying the whole array rather just the form element attribute which is clicked.

Any idea, what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a single form containing all the inputs. When you submit the form, all the inputs will be submitted.

Use a separate form for each product.

---

You also appear to be trusting the browser to tell you what the prices are. That's highly susceptible to tampering. You would be better of sending a product id and nothing else, and then looking up the prices on the server.

```
<button type="submit" 
        name="add_to_cart"
        value="your_product_id_12345">
Add to cart
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Quentin for your help, I was not aware of it. Would have saved few hours of work if I had let go my inhibition and asked.

Comment: Re sending prices: I think it is OK to send them *if* do not rely on them at all in server-side processing. They could be used as an extra check: if the price info in the form data does not match the info in your database, you know that there is something wrong (and probably need to take the data to manual processing—there might be a malevolent user tampering with the data, or you might have a mismatch between prices shown to customers and prices actually applied).